# How to display the popover content in another page?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am clicking the choose city on clicking that it will popover two cities one is 'bengaluru' and another one is 'hyderabad' if click that bengaluru it has to display that name instead of choose city..

home.html:

```
<ion-header>

<button ion-button icon-only (click)="presentPopover($event)" >
    Choose City
    <ion-label>{{cityname}}</ion-label>
  <ion-icon name="arrow-dropdown"></ion-icon>
</button>

</ion-header>
```

home.ts:

```
import { PopoverController } from 'ionic-angular';


import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Popoverpage} from '../popoverpage/popoverpage';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
   templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  constructor(public popoverCtrl: PopoverController,
    ) {}

  presentPopover(myEvent) {
    let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create(Popoverpage);
    popover.present({
      ev: myEvent
    });
  }
}
```

popoverpage.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Rest } from '../../providers/network/rest';
import { Logger } from '../../providers/logger/logger';

/*
  Generated class for the Popoverpage page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
*/
@Component({
  template: `
    <ion-list>
      <button ion-item (click)="store()">Bengaluru</button>
      <button ion-item (click)="fun()">Hyderabad</button>
    </ion-list>
  `
})

export class Popoverpage{
    store_id
  cityname


   constructor(public viewCtrl: ViewController,
     public params:NavParams,
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public rest: Rest,
    public logger: Logger) {
   }

  store() {
    let  storeObj={
      store_id: '1'
    }

    this.logger.debug("checking the  " +JSON.stringify(storeObj));

    this.rest.post('/store',storeObj)
      .subscribe(result => {
        this.logger.debug("checking the data "+JSON.stringify(result));
        if(result.status == '1'){
          this.logger.info("success callback");
          // this.navCtrl.push("Homepage");
          this.params.get('cityname');

          //this.navCtrl.pop();
          this.viewCtrl.dismiss();

        }
        else{
          this.logger.info("error callback");
this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
        }
      })

  }

  fun() {
    let  storeObj={
      store_id: '0'
    }

    this.logger.debug("checking the  " +JSON.stringify(storeObj));

    this.rest.post('/store',storeObj)
      .subscribe(result => {
        this.logger.debug("checking the data "+JSON.stringify(result));
        if(result.status == '1'){
          this.logger.debug("success callback");
          this.params.get('cityname');
          //this.navCtrl.pop();
           this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
        }
        else{
          this.logger.debug("error callback");
           this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
        }
      })

  }

}
```

how can i display that thing

Comment: you want pass data from popover to home page ?

Comment: exactly what u saying is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `dismiss` to pass data back and set a callback in `onDidDismiss`.
In the popoverpage.ts:

```
let data= cityname;//the variable containing the data to return
this.viewCtrl.dismiss({'city':data});
```

In your home.ts

```
  let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create(Popoverpage);

  popover.onDidDismiss(data=>{
     this.selectedCity=data.city;
  });

 popover.present({
      ev: myEvent
    });
```

Comment: we are getting [object] in that object we are not getting any thing

Comment: which object do you ned to return?

Comment: selectedcity we nead to return on home page

Comment: but it is return [object object]

Comment: `this.selectedCity=data.city;`

Comment: this.params.get('cityname') we are not getting any this  let data

Comment: what do you want to return from your popover?

Comment: city name  in home page